# Python syntax error when defining a mapping

Tags: python, syntax

I am using python 2.7.4 on a Linux machine. My guide is the book "Learn Python the hard way" and I am at 39th exercise and here's my code:

```
# states and their abberavation
states = [
'Bihar' : 'BIH'
'Jharkhand' : 'JK'
'Bengal' : 'BEN'
'Tamilnadu' : 'TN'
'Haryana' : 'HY'
'Kerla' : 'KER'
]

# states with their cities
cities = [
'BIH' : 'Patna'
'JK' : 'Ranchi'
'BEN' : 'Kolkatta'
]

# add some more cities
cities['CHN'] = 'Chennai'
cities['BWN'] = 'Bhiwani'

 #print out some cities
print '-' * 10
print "TN State has:", cities['CHN']
print "HY State has:", cities['BWN']

# print some states
print '-' * 10
print "Kerla's abbreviation is :", states['Kerla']
print "Jharkhand's abbreviation is:", states['Jharkhand']

# do it by using the state then cities dict
print '-' * 10
print "Bihar has:", cities[states['Bihar']]
print "Bengal has", cities[states['Bengal']]

# print every state abbreviation
print '-' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)

# print every city in state
print '-' * 10
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

# now do both at the same time
print '-' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" % (state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])

print '-' * 10
#safely get an abbreviation by state that might not be there
state = states.get('Maharashtra', None)

if not state:
    print "Sorry, no Maharashtra."

#get a city with a default value
city = cities.get('MH' 'Does Not Exist')
print "The city for the state 'MH' is: %s" % city
```

and the error I get is simply,

```
File "ex39.py", line 3
    'Bihar' : 'BIH'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried copy pasting the exact code but still I receive the same error. How is that colon responsible for the error? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `{..}` for dictionaries. `[..]` is a *list*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html Lecture for you

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax to define a dictionary. You need to use `{..}` (curly braces), not `[..]` (square brackets, used for lists):

```
# states and their abbreviation
states = {
    'Bihar': 'BIH',
    'Jharkhand': 'JK',
    'Bengal': 'BEN',
    'Tamilnadu': 'TN',
    'Haryana': 'HY',
    'Kerla': 'KER',
}

# states with their cities
cities = {
    'BIH': 'Patna',
    'JK': 'Ranchi',
    'BEN': 'Kolkatta',
}
```

The commas between key-value pairs are mandatory too.

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype  to define states, cities should be dictionary.

```
states = {
'Bihar' : 'BIH',
'Jharkhand' : 'JK',
'Bengal' : 'BEN',
'Tamilnadu' : 'TN',
'Haryana' : 'HY',
'Kerla' : 'KER'
}
```

You should change same for `cities`.
Please follow this link to learn about dictionary .[python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)